# How to set defaults values in LESS that can be over-ridden by users

Tags: less

Below is how I solved:

```
    .css-colors-default() {
        .css-keyword    {color: orange};    
        .css-property   {color: green}; //only here
    }
    .css-colors() {
        .css-keyword    {color: red};   
        .css-qualifier  {color: blue};  //only here
    }

#makeImportant() {                      //see !IMPORTANT note below
    .css-colors-default();
    .CSS {
        .css-colors(); 
        span.cm-m-css {
            &.cm-keyword    {.css-keyword};
            &.cm-property   {.css-property};
            &.cm-qualifier  {.css-qualifier};   
        }
    }
    //  important is required to override uses by code out of my control
} & { #makeImportant() !important}


This works but is creating extra CSS:

    .css-keyword {
        color: orange !important;
    }
    .css-property {
        color: green !important;
    }
    .CSS .css-keyword {
        color: red !important;
    }
    .CSS .css-qualifier {
        color: blue !important;
    }
    .CSS span.cm-m-css.cm-keyword {
        color: red !important;
    }
    .CSS span.cm-m-css.cm-property {
        color: green !important;
    }
    .CSS span.cm-m-css.cm-qualifier {
        color: blue !important;
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Many users will be designers familiar will css but not less.  Primary purpose is too allow designers to set tag colors although not shown in ex code. Initially for Dreamweaver but will port to other apps most notably devtools.

Example end game: [sample tag coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Rb3.png)

The inside of .css-colors() is all I intent to expose to users by default.

Comment: Are you asking how to to make things overridable in Less *itself*? (if so the easiest method is [variables](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20your%20code%5Cn%40some-color%3A%20green%3B%20%2F%2F%20default%20value%5Cn%5Cn.some-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20color%3A%20%40some-color%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20user%20code%20(anywhere%20after%20your%20code)%20%5Cn%40some-color%3A%20not-green%3B%20%2F%2F%20custom%20value%20%5Cn%22%7D)). Or are you asking of making things overridable in plain CSS?

Comment: Note the mixins cascade so variables inside mixins are overridable too ([example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20your%20code%5Cn%5Cn.my-colors()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20default%20values%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40some-color%3A%20green%3B%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.some-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.my-colors()%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%40some-color%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20user%20code%20%5Cn%5Cn.my-colors()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20custom%20values%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40some-color%3A%20not-green%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%20%5Cn%22%7D)). Etc. - the rest depends on your particular needs.

Comment: IMO class selectors seem less :) intimidating to Designers familiar with css but not less. The "extremely desirable" unexpected consequence was more flexibility e.g. .css-keyword {color: orange, font-weight: bold}; The extraneous css is small price for flexibility and css-like appearance. @seven-phases-max BTW: I have used many of your posts in getting up-to-speed with less.

Comment: Below is expanded less code exposed to Designer:

[sample less](http://i.imgur.com/rlOWNjw.png)

Comment: Full project: [Dreamweaver Custom Tag Code Coloring (CC 2017)](https://github.com/flkeysgeek/custom-tag-code-coloring)

Comment: @seven-phases-max your example is exactly the effect I want and in fact had initially coded using variables before discovering classes act like variables. The beauty of classes is explained above -- thanks!